# Order function does not order correctly

Tags: r

Both order and mixedorder does not work properly.

I had tried both order and mixorder. I use R3.6.1 version.

```
> x1
[1] 12 31 44 44 10
> class(x1)
[1] "numeric"
> order(x1)
[1] 5 1 2 3 4
> mixedorder(x1)
[1] 5 1 2 3 4
```

expected result was 2,3,4,5,1 when these 5 values are sorted.

Comment: Define working properly? What is the reason you expect 2,3,4,5,1? That fifth value is the smallest is it not?

Comment: Yes you are right. I was thinking it will give the order of 1st element when sorted. I totaly wrong understand the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to order the number sequence and then have 1 in the end? That doesn't seem like a standard order to me. Try ties.method.

Answer (score 0):

`?order`

> `order` returns a permutation which rearranges its first argument into ascending or descending order, breaking ties by further arguments.

`?rank`

> Returns the sample ranks of the values in a vector. Ties (i.e., equal values) and missing values can be handled in several ways.

It looks like you want `rank` instead of `order`